# OPENQUERY inside function

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, linked-server, openquery

I need to create a function that executes a query to a linked server through `openquery`, returning a scalar value.

My problem is that I cannot use a static query because one of the function parameters identifies the field that must be returned from OPENQUERY. So my first attempt was to build the query concatenating strings into an `@SQL` variable. But

```
select * from OPENQUERY(LNKSERVER,@SQL)
```

returns the error: `Expecting STRING or TEXT_LEX`

The solution to execute the query through linked server using a stored procedure is not applicable, because I'm inside a function.

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable  exec (@SQL) at LNKSERVER
```

By now I've solved selecting all possible columns, then UNPIVOTing them and selecting the row where PropertyName is the desidered one (but in my opinion it sucks).

```
SELECT @value = Value
FROM
(
    select 
        field1,
        field2,
        ...

        from OPENQUERY(LNKSERVER, 
 'SELECT 
    field1,
    field2,
    ...
  FROM table 
  INNER JOIN ...') 
        where  SampleId = @SampleId) qry
        UNPIVOT
        (
            Value FOR PropertyName IN (
                field1,
                field2,
                ... 
            )
        ) AS unpivoted

where PropertyName = @PropertyName
```

The drownbacks with this solution are the following:

1. Performance: query everytime for a lot of fields, not only the required one
2. Maintenance: each time I need to query for a new Property (not already included in function query), I also have to modify my function. So it is not good into a dynamic context.

I'm not an TSQL expert, so maybe someone can give me some hints to get things simplier?

Comment: **You can't use Dynamic-SQL inside function** see http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#UDF

Comment: tanks @lad2025 for you comment.. I've read about that. But I hope that there's some workaround better than mine to overcome this limitation..

Comment: Nope, with the limitations you've got, this is the solution I would go with.